# Java programing: trying to sort by age

Tags: java

I'm writing a small program that shows three professors and prints which one is oldest and youngest.  I thought my if statements were correct, but it prints out the same name for both statements.

```
public class app {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String initName = "Megan";
        String lastName = "Smith";
        String Degree = "Economics";
        int age = 40;
        professor2 pr1 = new professor2 (initName,lastName, Degree, age);

        professor2 pr2 = new professor2 ("John","White","Statistics", 55);

        professor2 pr3 = new professor2 ("Jill","Black","History", 60);


        //Check Oldest
        if ((pr1.getAge() > pr2.getAge()) && (pr1.getAge() > pr3.getAge())){
        System.out.println(pr1.getName() + " is older");}

        if ((pr2.getAge() > pr1.getAge()) && (pr2.getAge() > pr3.getAge())){
        System.out.println(pr1.getName() + " is older");}

        if ((pr3.getAge() > pr1.getAge()) && (pr3.getAge() > pr1.getAge())){
        System.out.println(pr1.getName() + " is older");}

        //Chech Youngest
        if ((pr1.getAge() < pr2.getAge()) && (pr1.getAge() < pr3.getAge())){
        System.out.println(pr1.getName() + " is younger");}

        if ((pr2.getAge() < pr1.getAge()) && (pr2.getAge() < pr3.getAge())){
        System.out.println(pr1.getName() + " is younger");}

        if ((pr3.getAge() < pr1.getAge()) && (pr3.getAge() < pr1.getAge())){
        System.out.println(pr1.getName() + " is younger");}

        }



    }

}
```

Then my second file is:

```
public class professor2 {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String Degree;
    int age;

    professor2 (String myFirstName, String myLastName,String myDegree, int myAge)
    {
    firstName = myFirstName;
    lastName= myLastName;
    Degree = myDegree;
    age = myAge;
    }

    String getName()
    {
    return firstName + " " +lastName;
    }

    String getDegree()
    {
    return Degree;
    }

    int getAge()
    {
    return age;
    }
}
```

Comment: In each case you print `pr1.getName()`; it's probably a copy/paste bug.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have copy-pasted the same statement here. Regardless of the condition in the `if`, you're printing `pr1`'s details. Fixing those statements should give you the right output:

```
//Check Oldest
if ((pr1.getAge() > pr2.getAge()) && (pr1.getAge() > pr3.getAge())) {
    System.out.println(pr1.getName() + " is older");
}

if ((pr2.getAge() > pr1.getAge()) && (pr2.getAge() > pr3.getAge())) {
    System.out.println(pr2.getName() + " is older"); // here
}

if ((pr3.getAge() > pr1.getAge()) && (pr3.getAge() > pr1.getAge())) {
    System.out.println(pr3.getName() + " is older"); // and here
}

//Check Youngest
if ((pr1.getAge() < pr2.getAge()) && (pr1.getAge() < pr3.getAge())) {
    System.out.println(pr1.getName() + " is younger");
}

if ((pr2.getAge() < pr1.getAge()) && (pr2.getAge() < pr3.getAge())) {
    System.out.println(pr2.getName() + " is younger"); // and here
}

if ((pr3.getAge() < pr1.getAge()) && (pr3.getAge() < pr1.getAge())) {
    System.out.println(pr3.getName() + " is younger"); // and here
}
```

This approach works, but it doesn't scale. What if you have ten professors? Or a hundred? Or a thousand?
A more robust solution may be to store these objects in a collection and sort it using a custom comparator:

```
List<professor2> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(pr1, pr2, pr3);
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<professor2>() {
        @Override
        public int compare (professor2 p1, professor2 p2) {
            return Integer.compare(p1.getAge(), p2.getAge());
        }
    }
);
System.out.println ("The oldest is " + list.get(list.size() - 1).getName());
System.out.println ("The youngest is " + list.get(0).getName());
```

Comment: Nit: the sorting approach doesn't give exactly the same output, since the code above will not print in the case that there are two professors with the same age that is the greatest (or smallest).

Answer (score 0):

Dijam how  will  you  come  up  with  oldest  and  youngest  logic  that  way?i think  once  you put  sorted  age ...then map  with  name in hashmap.And when one ask for a youngest  or  oldest  go search in the sorted  list and  retrieve name in a Hashmap?

Answer (score 0):

***01.***

You are printing name of `pr1` every time!

```
System.out.println(pr1.getName() + " is older");
```

Change the object of `professor2` class in the above line in each `if` block according to the logic of respective `if` statement.

***02.***

The **3rd** `if` statement:

```
if ((pr3.getAge() > pr1.getAge()) && (pr3.getAge() > pr1.getAge())){
        System.out.println(pr1.getName() + " is older");}
```

You are comparing `pr3` with `pr1` twice. But you need to compare `pr3` once with `pr1` and once with `pr2`.

***03.***

Same for the **6th** if statement:

```
if ((pr3.getAge() < pr1.getAge()) && (pr3.getAge() < pr1.getAge())){
        System.out.println(pr1.getName() + " is younger");}
```

Compare `pr3` with both `pr1` and `pr2`. Not with `pr1` twice.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the same every time:

```
System.out.println(pr1.getName() + " is _____");}
```

Use the professor that you want to print out at each `if` statement.